# How do I remove a video driver that breaks my system?

Tags: 13.10, nvidia, login

I recently installed an nVidia driver from the nVidia website that has since prevented me from logging in. I can get to the login page, but after I enter my password, my screen goes black with just the cursor. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can try:

1. Login with Guest session, and see if you have the previleges to install/uninstall
2. If your system is dual-booted, you my see a grub menu when starting. Switch to recovery mode on grub menu and see if you can do somehting on the terminal
3. If you know a way to fix the problem by just editing some files manually, you can start another Ubuntu from your installation CD (or usb stick), and edit your original system files, which is mounted as a folder in the /media directory.

Comment: It would be helpful if you actually told me what to do instead of how to get to a place where I can do it. I know how to get into terminal and all that, but I need to know what to do once I get there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove all the packages that was related to nvidia.So on the login screen press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.It will open an virtual console.Login in that console.

After logged in, run the below commands,

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Comment: This removed 4 packages, but I still have the same issue. One thing that I find interesting is that my laptop power button changes color when my GPU is being used over my integrated graphics, and when I'm in ubuntu it is always on. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: After that try to remove xorg.conf file by running `sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Comment: No such file...

Comment: And also try to remove Xauthority file by running `sudo rm ~/.Xauthority`

Comment: No love... still black screen with only cursor.

Comment: Any other ideas?